# Will the MAS prompt me to keep my Xcode 5?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, xcode, software-update

I have Xcode 5.11. If I try to install the newest (6.0) Xcode from the Mac App Store, will I be prompted to keep my current Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, Xcode 6 on the Mac App Store will replace the existing Xcode installation. Only the Xcode betas install separately (by default) and only downloading Xcode from developer.apple.com and doing the install manually (by copying Xcode from the DMG to /Applications) will prompt you to replace or keep both.

Comment: THANKS!

This is what I thought, but this answer on SO -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/26674417/8047 -- makes me think that... maybe there's an option?

Also: what if I rename my Xcode 5? The app is 8gb so I assume it contains something, but... can that run independently?

Comment: @Yar If you manually download Xcode.app from developer.apple.com then the installation process will involve you dragging the Xcode.app to the Applications folder, at which point you will get the standard Finder alert to replace the existing file. The Mac App Store simply replaces the existing Xcode. Yes, you can rename your existing Xcode and the Mac App Store should not touch it, but to be extra sure, take a copy of it somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice it before. https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/ -> Additional Tools (View Downloads)... perfect, thanks!